# Workouts provoke tension problem with sleep

Tags: workout

Something days i cant sleep because i have tension (or hypertension I am not sure the right word) its caused by workouts.The problem is I have try much but nothing helps.Example I want to sleep 12:00 at night but I can't because of that.How can overcome that and have a nice sleep?I can't sleep not a minute.I tried walking ,some exercises ,yoga ,sleeping sound hypnosis and many but I can't.

Comment: No but quite good. We are talking about tension.Which provoked by workouts.Those ways are relaxing we talk how to stop tension.Tension is that someone needs to do things can't close eyes this is just relaxing.I hope you understand me. He says he can. I can't

Comment: I'm going to say that "tension" (your word) and "restlessness" (the other question) are pretty well linked together.

Comment: Tension is completely different situations from restlessness.Let me explain,if you workout too much your nerves ,arent working good meaning your endurance become   tired from whole day workouts then the night you have feelings.Why?When 
you tired you think more as a result  your system can't get sleep and become night-anger provoke tension.